# Static Method That Finds Sum of All Even Numbers in a List

Tags: c#, .net, list

Beginner at C#. I'm familiar with Python, and in Python, (I think) you would do something like this:

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

def SumOfEvens(myList):

    #Initialize the results variable.
    result = 0  

    #Loop through each element of the list.
    for i in myList:  

    #Test for even numbers.
        if not i % 2:  
        result += i

return(result)

print SumOfEvens(myList)
30
```

I'm trying to recreate this in C#, except that I need to write a static method and then call that method on a list within `Main`

So far this is what I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Strings
{
class Program
    {
        static void SumofEvens(string[] args)
        {
        //initialize results variable
        int result = 0

        //check if the number is even. If it's even, add it.
        foreach (int i in l)
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                int result += i
            }

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
            return SumofEvens(l);
        }
    }
}
```

To start with, I don't know how to properly create the list `l` within main. Is the correct way to do it like this?

`int[] l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

Then I need to write the result of `Main` to the console. Would that be

```
Console.WriteLine(Main);
Console.ReadLine();
```

And where would it go at the very bottom of my code? Currently that just tells the Console to say "enter an integer". Thanks for any help.

Comment: check out Maksim Simkin's answer.
It's elegant, readable and precise.

Comment: @OriNachum It's precise but it doesn't answer many of my questions + it doesn't provide any explanations. Type 'var' before the variable to declare a variable....type '<int>' before {} to declare the items as integers....Why is he doing these things as opposed to what arias_JC and nabil london did, where the array is created like this: 'int[] l = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};'? Also he doesn't answer my question about where I should write to the console.

Comment: He's using linq, and I recommend learning and using it. It allows you to do a lot of on enumerable objects in one action. 'var' can be replaced with *any* variable in a scope (Not as class variable), as long as it is clear what the variable is on compile time. The first line defines the array, and prepares the values he wrote there. The second line is actually 2 actions: 1. "take only those that match the rule in brackets and put in a temporary array";  2. "Sum the new temporary array."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating an array can be done by:

```
int[] l = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
```

Alternatively, if your creating an array within a range:

```
int[] l = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToArray();
```

You would need to include `System.linq` for the above. Writing to console would be

```
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

But you would not return a value in main since you defined it as void, you would call your method and either print result in your static method or print the result in main by returning the result:

```
static int SumofEvens(string[] args)
{
  ...
  // either print in method, the above return would be void
  Console.WriteLine(result);
  // or return result, the above return would be int as shown
  return result;
}

// if SumofEvens returns int, in main ...
Console.WriteLine(SumofEvens());
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var l =new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
var result = l.Where(i=>i%2==0).Sum();
```

Comment: As a C# programmer I felt really good reading your answer in contrast to the Python in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Strings
{
    class Program
    {
        // method SumOfEvens take an int array and returns an int
        static int SumOfEvens(int[] integers)
        {
            //initialize results variable
            int result = 0

            //check if the number is even. If it's even, add it.
            foreach (int i in integers)
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    int result += i
                }
            // You should return the result
            return result;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // that's how you create an array of integers in c#
            int[] integers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

            // store the sum in a variable
            int result = SumOfEvens(integers);

            // write result to the console
            Console.WriteLine("The sum of even integers is: "+ result);

            // never return something in the Main method
            // because it returns void (nothing)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight forward approach with linq

```
 using System.Linq;
 static int SumofEvens(int[] Arr)
 {
      return Arr.Where(number=>number%2==0).Sum();
 }
```